# Test project icon not visible in android

Tags: android, robotium

I am unit testing an android applications using Robitium. When I install the test project in to android emulator, I can't find the icon of the test project, but I can run it.

The manifest file of the test project is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.smartek.screens.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<instrumentation
    android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:targetPackage="com.smartek.screens" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

<uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
</application>
```

What should I do to make the test project icon visible?

Answer (score 2):

The test project will not contain the launcher entry in manifest file, so you cannot see the icon on launcher.

```
<intent-filter>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this and its same as the normal android application .

Add the following lines to the android manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".Testing class name">

<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>

</activity>
```